# Getting "command requires scopes" error when starting firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm trying to start firebase functions emulator locally on macOS but getting the following error:

> firebase emulators:start --only functions --debug

```
command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2022-05-30T13:15:53.611Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (xxx@xxx.xxx)
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: functions"}}
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Shutting down emulators."}}
[2022-05-30T13:15:53.863Z] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
    at Object.startAll (/Users/lm/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/controller.js:249:77)
    at Command.actionFn (/Users/lm/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/emulators-start.js:28:52)
    at /Users/lm/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:190:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I have done this a hundred times but for some reason it decided to stop working now. I have tried to logout and login again but it didn't help. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the exactly the same error by adding firebase hosting to firebase init by using the cli (regardless of whether you use firebase hosting or not).

[image: cli]

Edit:
This caused the problem: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/commit/78c01b9716630d74a66c0c7ca791efca47704083#diff-415db4c4ed23f67072ca1cb7b66b0ad6f9f13ede99bbb1e17e06409d75016e4e=

The error is fixed with v11.1.0

Comment: I'm getting this error now, after upgrading to firebase `v11.18.0`